# VBA Excel WebScraping

Tags: excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I have a project that I need to web scrape a different number of currencies values (around 15 of them). For one scraping this code below works fine, but how can I code this for consulting a lot of currencies?

***Each currency have a specific link.**

```
Sub currence()

    Range("A5:A16").ClearContents

    'AED
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.navigate "https://br.investing.com/currencies/aed-brl"

    Do While ie.busy And ie.readyState <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set HTML = ie.Document
    Cells(5, 1) = HTML.getElementsByClassName("top bold inlineblock")(0).innerText

    Debug.Print Cells(5, 1)
    ie.Quit

    Range("A5:A16").WrapText = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Create an array of the links and loop over it?

Comment: @BigBen yes i think about it, but don't know exactly how the code look like.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub currence()
Dim myURL() As Variant
Dim html As Object
Dim a As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Cells.Clear
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://br.investing.com/currencies", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    For Each a In html.getElementsByClassName("bold left noWrap elp plusIconTd")
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve myURL(1 To i)
        myURL(i) = Replace(a.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href, "about:", "https://br.investing.com")
    Next a
    For j = LBound(myURL) To UBound(myURL)
        .Open "GET", myURL(j), False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        r = r + 1
        Cells(r, 1) = UCase(Split(myURL(j), "/")(4))
        Cells(r, 2) = html.getElementsByClassName("top bold inlineblock")(0).innerText
    Next j
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi Ges, i can't use this board because i need the compare"BRL vs OTHER CURRENCY". This code return "error 438 object doesn't support this property or method".